# FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'

Tags: flutter

I was developing a project in Android Studio with Flutter, I received some error messages recommending that I update the version of flutter that I was using.
I did a flutter upgrade, but now when I want to run the app on the emulator I get an error that I don't know how to fix.
Somebody could help me?
Thank you.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'C:\palser delivery app\palser delivery app\android\build.gradle' line: 27
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.

> A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
> > Could not create task ':app:compileDebugAndroidTestKotlin'.
> > Cannot use @TaskAction annotation on method AbstractKotlinCompile.execute() because interface org.gradle.api.tasks.incremental.IncrementalTaskInputs is not a valid parameter to an action method.
> > KotlinJvmAndroidCompilation with name 'debugAndroidTest' not found.

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

My build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I appreciate help to solve the error and be able to run the app in the emulator.